# Network configuration timed out in Ubuntu Core 16 for Wifi adapter on RPI3

Tags: ubuntu-core

I am trying to configure Ubuntu Core on RPI3 for the first time, during its own configuration it stop in "Network Configuration". Clicking "Done" at 66% it gives me an error.

[image]

I tried to reboot the RPI and I saw that

[image]

from my Desktop I can ping its IP addr, and it's right also the Gateway

[image]

but if I try to set "Done" the same issue

[image]

using a cable connection I've any issues and can proceed completing the set, with wifi no. In the SD card the contents is this:

[image]

how do I have to set also wifi connection on it? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved that set first the cable interface (eth0) then from terminal and using vi I've added also the wifi interface. The guide was that:

```
$: ifconfig wlan0 down
$: ifconfig wlan0 up
```

create wireless config file:

```
$: sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0
```

add the following content

```
auto wlan0 
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-essid WIRELESSSSID 
wpa-psk WIRELESSPASSWORD
```

reboot the Ubuntu Core and also wifi adapter is up

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue when I run ubuntu core 16.04 on RPI3.
Creating wireless config file method mentioned by Riccardo Magrini.

`$: sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0`

does not work perfectly. Because wlan0 interface can obtain IP config
and I can ssh to RPI3 from local network.
But default gateway is missing. 
Even if try dhcpclient wlan0, the default gateway does not apply.

My solution is:

1. setup the cable interface (eth0)
2. SSH to RPI to get a terminal
3. do

   `$sudo snap refresh`
4. wait RPI3 reboot and connect it via SSH again.
5. reconfig wlan0 inerface

   `$sudo console-conf`
6. unplug network cable, and reboot.

Comment: Actually, in ubuntu core 16, even there is no eth0 file in interface.d folder. I tried to put one in, but it never affect setting of eth0. I guess the only way to change nic setting, is using console-conf.

Comment: The config file of console-conf is /etc/netplan/00-snapd-config.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately things like this are very hard to debug. The part that's timing out is waiting for a default route to appear. If you pull the SD card from the pi3 and stick it in a computer, the contents of the file at /writable/system-data/var/log/console-conf/subiquity-debug.log would be interesting (use a pastebin, I guess).

Comment: I don't find that path....I've posted the screen upgraded the post

Answer (score 0):

In my test scenario, Core 16 on Raspberry Pi 3, there is no file in /etc/network/interfaces.d. And if you want to put some file into it, it will never be affected.

The best way to change the network config, is using console-conf. You could change the config file yourself(/etc/netplan/00-snapd-config.yaml), but it will not be applied to system automatically.

Back to your case: There really is something wrong with console-conf. Every time you setup wifi (even the built in wifi on my RP3), it will failed with time out error. But if you just need to use wifi with DHCP, you could simply do this:

1. Boot;
2. Login with your local account;
3. sudo console-conf
4. Enter the SSID and password setting of Wifi;
5. Choose Done;
6. When it says timed out, hit Ctrl-Alt-Del to reboot your system.

You will find it works...